# Automatic crafting available receipts in excel for ttrpg

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that will help my players with crafting.
The core problem is:

- you have an inventory
- you can craft items with the materials
- some items require other crafted items to be made

The basic receipts is:

| Final item | Subassembly |
| --- | --- |
| component 1 | Component 1 |
| subassembly | Component 2 |

The final item can be made or by using 1x component 1 and 1x subassembly, or by using 2x component 1 and 1x component 2. Of cure basing on what you have in the inventory.

I tried as follows, but i have problems with the component 1 (in inventory i have 1x comp 1 and 1x comp 2:

|FI.  |comp. 1|subbass|--|req. qty 1|req. qty 1|--|inv. qty 1|inv.qty 0|--|craftable 1
|sub. |comp. 1|comp. 2|--|req. qty 1|req. qty 1|--|inv. qty 1|inv.qty 1|--|craftable 1

To calculate the craftable quantity i divide the inventory quantity by the req. quantity, if one item appears in the first column i add the craftable quantity of it to the division.
The problem is that in reality i need 2x comp 1, but i cannot figure out how to make this "recursive" sum in the quantity needed.

To make it scalable i don't want to create a receipt like:

|FI.  |comp. 1|comp. 2|--|req. qty 2|req. qty 1|--|inv. qty 1|inv.qty 1|--|craftable 0

The main problem: i'd like to make visible when the basic components can make the final item, but i cannot figure out how to solve this...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.